# .net core nginx hosting sockets doesn't allow http post

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, websocket

I am trying to make a website that would have http functions including http post functions, and also web sockets (such as signalR). I am trying to host this website on an ubuntu server using nginx. Generally the set up is something like this on nginx:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
}
```

However, I later found that I need to add `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";` in order to use websockets. However, adding this line in a .net core project results in all http post requests showing a 400 error as shown here [400 status error when posting form data in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529210/400-status-error-when-posting-form-data-in-asp-net-core). Is there a set up that would allow both posts and web sockets?

Answer (score 8):

using $http_connection instead of keep-alive or upgrade

```
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

Comment: Perfect! It works! Could you please give a short explanation what this change does?

Comment: This works partially for me.
Websocket works, POST request works but now I have a new problem where after logging it with Identity Server, it redirects me to the callback page without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fix to your question, but may be a workaround. I got around this by setting up 2 proxy locations in nginx to a single asp.net core kestrel site. One for the websockets with the

```
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

and one for everything else. Looks like this. Top one is for all but websockets, bottom is for websockets. Note I have rewrites also.

```
location /n/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
}

location /nsock/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

Comment: Why are you rewriting every request?

Comment: Using the top configuration, it basically removes "n/" from the URL as it proxies the asp.net core site. For example this URL http://hostname/n/api/entries is proxied to the 5001 port as http://hostname:5001/api/entries. Note there is no "n/". I am doing this because there are several kestrel instances running on different ports and I proxy to them from different "sub web folders" in the regular 80/443 nginx ports.

Comment: No need for a rewrite, which causes Nginx to process the request all over again. You just need to change your proxy pass to `proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;`, same for the second directive

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the trailing slash would work like that on proxy_pass. Works exactly as you said w/o the rewrite. This is running on a Pi so it thanks you for not having process each request twice in nginx. I edited my snippet above in case anyone stumbles across it.

Comment: It works like this: `proxy_pass` to a naked url, i.e. nothing at all after domain/ip/port and the full client request url gets passed to the proxy. Add anything, even just a slash to the `proxy_pass` and whatever you add replaces the part of the client request url which matches that location block. So if you had `location /foo { proxy_pass http://example.com/bar;` then a client request for `example.com/foo/baz` would get proxied to `example.com/bar/baz`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration for .Net Core API with nginx:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

The main idea are remove these lines (if you have)

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

and insert this line in your configuration

```
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

Hope it helps.